# ユーザーの入力間違えによる、エラーの出力方法について

Tags: php

現在、PHPの勉強としまして、簡易な掲示板のサイトを作成しているのですが、ユーザーが投稿されたコメント欄の削除パスワードを間違えて入力してしまった際に、どのように画面に表示させるか、といった部分でうまくいかず、お力をお貸し頂きたく、ご質問させて頂きました。
削除パスワードが入力され、データベースに接続し、格納されているコメントの削除処理を記載したコードは、以下の「delete1.php」になります。

```
<?php 
include 'bbs_class1.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$errs = [];
$bbs = new Bbs('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=online_bbs;charset=utf8', 'root', '12345', 10);
if(!empty($_POST)){

  $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password');
  $id = intval(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id'));

  if(!$password){
    $errs[] = 'パスワードを入力してください';
  }elseif(!preg_match('/\A[a-z\d]{8,100}+\z/i',$password)){
    $errs[] = 'パスワードは半角英数8文字以上で入力してください';
  }


  if(!$id){
    $errs[] = 'idが送信されていません';
  }

  if(empty($errs)){
    try{
      $bbs->delete($id,$password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    header('Location:bbs1.php');
    exit();
  }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <?php if(!empty($errs)): ?>
        <?php echo implode('<br />',$errs); ?>
        <a href="bbs1.php">戻る</a>

      <?php endif;?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

データベースの接続処理などをまとめたクラスである、「bbs_class1.php」の削除処理、及びデータベース接続処理をまとめたメソッドが以下のコードとなります。

```
public function delete($id,$password){

            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM post_3 WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $db_password = $stmt->fetchColumn();
            //var_dump($db_password);
            if(!password_verify($password,$db_password)){
                throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');
            }

            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM post_3 WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();           
    }
```

実は、「delete1.php」の

```
if(empty($errs)){
    try{
      $bbs->delete($id,$password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    header('Location:bbs1.php');
    exit();
  }
```

こちらの部分におきまして、エラーメッセージを出力させようと思ったのですが、fatalエラーが発生してしまい、エラーメッセージのみを出力させることができません。
また、try,catch文内のcatchにて、deleteメソッドの「throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');」ここの部分で例外をスローしたものをメッセージとして出力する処理にした場合、仮に、データベースに接続できないなどの、エラーが発生した場合は、スローした例外と、データベースエラーのどちらのメッセージがdelete1.phpの`catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}`のメッセージとして出力されるのかなども疑問です...
どなたか、ご教示いただける方いらっしゃいましたら、ご助言頂けましたら幸いです。

---

※以下は頂きましたご回答を踏まえ、修正&追記しましたコードになります。
まず、新たにパスワード認証用の例外クラスを作成致しました。
以下は、「exception.php」になります。

```
    <?php
class PasswordException extends Exception{
  public function __construct($message){
    parent::__construct($message);
  }
}
```

以下はbbs_class1.phpのdeleteメソッドを修正したものになります。

```
public function delete($id,$password){

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM post_3 WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db_password = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        //var_dump($db_password);
        if(!password_verify($password,$db_password)){
            throw new PasswordException('パスワードが違います');                
        }

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM post_3 WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();           
}
```

以下は、delete1.phpのdeleteメソッド呼び出し部分を修正したコードになります。

```
if(empty($errs)){
    try{
      $bbs->delete($id,$password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }catch(PasswordException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit();
    }

    header('Location:bbs1.php');
    exit();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` の仕様として「引数で指示されている種類の例外のみを受け取る」ので、提示コードの `catch (PDOException $e)` は `PDOException` およびその派生クラスの例外だけを捕捉し、他の種類の例外は捕捉しません。

提示例では、投げている例外が `throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');` なので `PDOException` には該当せず、よって提示コードだけでは捕捉されません。

`catch` は１か所に複数個書けるので、試してみましょう。

`catch (Exception)` は「すべての例外」を捕捉するので先に書いた通り「デバッグできなくなる典型コード」となってしまいます。業務例外とシステム例外が区別できるよう `Exception` を直接使うのでなくて一度派生させて使うほうが良いです。(`PDOException` はシステム例外、パスワードが違うのは業務例外）とりあえず業務例外専用クラス `MyException` とか作って `throw MyException(...)` `catch (MyException)` してみましょう。

Comment: ご回答頂きまして、ありがとうございます。
オブジェクト指向を勉強していくにあたり、例外の理解もきちんとしていかなければと思っていたので、大変助かりました。
実の所「PDOException」こちらはデータベース接続の際に起こった例外クラスというのを理解できておらず、try,catch文内に書かれた処理で例外が発生したらすべてここで受け取るものだと、大変な認識間違いをしていました...
業務例外やシステム例外などについても、詳しく教えて頂きましたおかげで、
ご解説頂きました「業務例外専用クラス MyException とか作って throw MyException(...) catch (MyException) してみましょう。」ここの部分も理解することができました。新たに、教えて頂きました点を、踏まえコードを修正致しましたので、そちらのコードを質問本文に追記させて頂きます。

Comment: 質問本文に追記致しました。
すみません。もし、可能でしたらチェック頂けましたら幸いです...